# Delphi FireDAC connect timeout or force abort connection establishing process

Tags: database, delphi, networking, firedac

Does anyone know if there is a way to force abort connection that is being established in background thread? Or at least define connect timeout?

A couple of notes

1. Leaving background thread running and just forgetting about it is not an option.
2. Went through source code and available properties - could not find anything related to the question.

Comment: That is a DBMS dependent setting. What's more, if the driver API connection function is blocking, you can't do muchfor its termination (only leave the thread to finish such call, or kill it forcefully with possible consequences). But many DBMSs offer `LoginTimeout` kind of parameters for this purpose.

Comment: Hi Victoria thanks for the comment. Yes figured that much. However I found workaround. Basically I created custom TCP connection to database server just to check if the server is available. Normally I could leave the thread running, but Firebird driver locks down and waits for the pending connection to finish and does not allow to establish additional connection while previous connection is in progress.

Comment: Yes, because it's a blocking call. But specifically Firebird seems to implement `connect_timeout` parameter (`isc_dpb_connect_timeout` to be precise). Specify it in the `IBAdvanced` [connection parameter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Connect_to_Firebird_(FireDAC)#Connection_Definition_Parameters). If you said you are using Firebird, I could answer you pretty quickly.

Comment: @RelateX It would help if you included what you've already tried. Lots of people come here and ask really broad questions like this all the time. You're fortunate someone noticed this one or it would have eventually been removed. Editing some details about what you're trying to do would help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that FireDAC (Data Access Library) only describes the Technology from Delphi to simplify accessing Data on several Databases.
To define a Timeout on your connection, the Database Connection has to Support that.
Here is the Describtion for a Connectiontimeout in, for example, an Interbase Connection via FireDAC.
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FireDAC.Phys.IBBase.TFDIBService.ConnectTimeout

Comment: Thanks fisi-pjm. I am aware of what you are saying and have read the article. The goal of the question was to check if there is some sort of property or function which could be used to accomplish this that I have missed. P.S. The article refers to FireDAC IB Service components not the actual connection to IB with which you can perform queries etc. FireDAC connection component and IB Driver link does not contain connection timeout property as far as I know. Which again was the original question.